# An Access Problem:How to Set Access Report paper size A3 through VBA code

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to set access report paper size to A3 permanently whenever user print it through VBA
code .
For that I have written this code which I have found over net

```
Option Compare Database

Type gtypStr_DEVMODE
    RGB As String * 94
End Type

Type gType_DEVMODE
    strDeviceName As String * 32
    intSpecVersion As Integer
    intDriverVersion As Integer
    intSize As Integer
    intDriverExtra As Integer
    lngFields As Long
    intOrientation As Integer
    intPaperSize As Integer
    intPaperLength As Integer
    intPaperWidth As Integer
    intScale As Integer
    intCopies As Integer
    intDefaultSource As Integer
    intPrintQuality As Integer
    intColor As Integer

    intDuplex As Integer
    intResolution As Integer
    intTTOption As Integer
    intCollate As Integer
    strFormName As String * 32
    lngPad As Long
    lngBits As Long
    lngPW As Long
    lngPH As Long
    lngDFI As Long
    lngDFr As Long
End Type

Sub SetToA3(pReport As String)

    Dim LDevString As gtypStr_DEVMODE
    Dim LDM As gType_DEVMODE
    Dim LDevModeExtra As String
    Dim LRpt As Report

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    'Open report in Design view
    DoCmd.OpenReport pReport, acDesign
    Set LRpt = Reports(pReport)

    'Change paper size to legal
    If Not IsNull(LRpt.PrtDevMode) Then

        LDevModeExtra = LRpt.PrtDevMode
        LDevString.RGB = LDevModeExtra
        LSet LDM = LDevString

        '5=legal, 1=standard
        LDM.intPaperSize = 256
        LSet LDevString = LDM
        Mid(LDevModeExtra, 1, 94) = LDevString.RGB
        LRpt.PrtDevMode = LDevModeExtra

    End If

    'Save report changes (suppress system messages temporarily)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.Save acReport, pReport
    DoCmd.Close acReport, pReport
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "Changing paper size to legal failed."
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work at all, i.e. when I call SettoA3 procedure nothing happen.

Why not?

Comment: That's the ancient PrntMps method of controlling the printer, which dates back to Access 2 (and maybe before). If you're using any version of Access from 2002 on, you now have a Printer object to make this much easier (though still not nearly as easy as it ought to be). I don't use it myself, so can't offer code, but you should have a look at the help files to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I don't believe you wrote that code your self (a link to where you found it would have been helpful, I found about 20 references to it) but you probably want to change `LDM.intPaperSize = 256` to `LDM.intPaperSize = acPRPSA3`.

I found this on [MS's page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/papersize-property-HA001232779.aspx) (it's hidden in the dropdown for AcPrintPaperSize

Comment: yes ,this is true i did'nt write this code ,i used it over the net.code is ok or not

Comment: have a form in access 2010 in which there is a pdf icon,whenever user is click that icon ,

a access report is automatically open in pdf format.

The problem is that the content is split into two page.so i goto print priview and set the size of report to A3 .And again do the same but this time report is displayed well in one page.

it works well for my computer,but i check it on other computer and it's still displayed into two page.

so that i want to open a report on the click of pdf icon and  set the paper size of my report to A3 permanently through VBA coding.

Comment: plz what i do in this scenario?

Comment: Using the code - it depends where you are and what for. Just because it is on the internet doesn't make it copyright free. My point was that a link to the source might have helped us help you understand it better.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do what you want to do. It may in fact be impossible (or VERY impractical), due to configuration differences between computers.

Comment: Thank's dear,I have used your suggested link and It works for me!I am really very happy thanks again